# Instant Run-Off Calculator for Excel or Google Apps

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, google-forms

I'm looking for a script to tally the results of an election in Google Forms using Instant Run-Off.  I've been unable to find a simple way to run this in python, excel, or Google Apps. Has anyone else already solved this problem? Thanks

Here is an example output for one of the races.

```
Frank Castle    Frank Underwood Frank Sinatra 
0               0               0
0               0               0
1               2               3
2               1               3
0               0               0
0               0               0
0               0               0
0               0               0
1               2               3
0               0               0
3               2               1
```

Comment: It appears as though all you want to do is sum each of those three columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MattCremeens It's not quite that simple. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting#Five_voters.2C_three_candidates).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) google for google apps script. its offtopic to ask for a recommendation.

Comment: This can be done in Google Apps Script.  If the data is already in a Google Form, then the easiest language to use would be Apps Script.  Apps Script is written in the script editor.  The script editor can be opened directly from the Google Form by clicking "Tools" then "Script Editor" in Old Google Form.  In new Google Form, click the "three dot" icon, and choose "Script Editor." You might want to ask the question in the Apps Script Community:  [Link to Google Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)